# elemento keyup en elemento v-if

Tags: vue.js

Tengo un input que solo se muestra si la variable es true y ese input tiene un @keyup, pero no funciona, hay alguna manera de hacer que funcione el keyup en este elemento dinamico

aqui mi codigo

```
 <div class="mb-4" v-if="height">
    <jet-label for="height" value="Altura"/>
    <jet-input id="height" type="number" class="mt-1 block w-full uppercase" v-model="form.height" v-on:keyup="calculate_mm2()"/>
    <jet-input-error v-if="errors.height" :message="errors.height[0]" class="mt-2" />
 </div>
```

Comment: v-on:keyup.enter="submit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucione el problema usando keyup de la siguiente forma:

```
@keyup.native="calculate_mm2()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar  `keyup.enter`

```
v-on:keyup.enter ="calculate_mm2()"
```

o

```
@keyup="calculate_mm2()"
```

Comment: Hello, the solution you propose does not work for me